# How to insert values from numpy into sql database with given columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, mysql-python

I need to insert some columns into a table in my Mariadb.  The table name is Customer and has 6 columns, A,B,C,D,E,F.  The primary keys are in the first column, column B has an address, C,D, and E contain None values and F the zip code.

I have an pandas dataframe that follows similar format.  I converted it to numpy array by doing the following:

```
data = df.iloc[:,1:4].values
```

hence data is a numpy array containing 3 columns and i need this inserted into C,D and E.  I tried:

```
query = """
Insert Into Customer (C,D,E) VALUES (?,?,?)
"""
cur.executemany(query,data)
cur.commit()
```

But i get an error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  Although very slow...

```
query = """
Alter Customer SET
C = %s
D = %s
E = %s
where A = %s
"""

for row in data:
    cur.execute(query,args=(row[1],row[2],row[3],row[0])
con.commit()
```